# OpenLayers CSS Styling of Standard Control Buttons

Tags: javascript, css, button, openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers on a script on my page, and I'm trying to use CSS to style the standard buttons that come on the map.  I followed the OpenLayers docs site in styling them like so:

```
.olControlNavToolbar div {
  display:block;
  width:  28px;
  height: 28px;
  top: 300px;
  left: 6px;
  position: relative;
}
.olControlNavToolbar .olControlNavigationItemActive {
  background-image: url("img/panning-hand-on.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.olControlNavToolbar .olControlNavigationItemInactive {
  background-image: url("img/panning-hand-off.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

But no matter which CSS settings I change in the above code, nothing changes on the map.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can style (move/resize/modify) the existing/default OpenLayers buttons that appear on a given map?

Comment: If the background images are the buttons you speak of, then you have to change the background images to something else.  Otherwise, I see nothing else in your posted code that would have anything to do with buttons.

Comment: @Sparky672 - Yes, I can change the background images, but I want to know how to style them in CSS. The OpenLayers documentation said I could style the toolbar (pan,zoom,etc) with css using the '.oldControlNavToolbar' syntax. I'm okay with the current images, I just want to move their location. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You have not posted enough code (HTML) nor explained how you _"just wanted to move their location"_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The custom control example explains why this is, but basically, Openlayers is dynamically loading a CSS file over yours and squashing your changes because it was added later.

You should create your map with the 'theme' option set to null; {'theme: null} in map options. Then, include the default CSS (theme/default/style.CSS) before yours, and all should be well.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989173/openlayers-not-using-theme-css). If you don't reference 'themes/default/style.css' file, path to images is defined inline rather that in CSS classes you mentioned above.