# OpenLayers not using theme CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, themes, openlayers

I need to customize the position (using CSS) of some of the elements, but when I change the style.css document in the theme/default directory inside OpenLayers, the CSS changes are not applied to the Map. 
Additionally, the icons contained inside the theme/default/img directory for the map are not used. Instead the icons residing in the base /img directory are used.

Does anyone know how to tell OpenLayers to use the CSS and images from a specific theme? 
How do I tell OpenLayers to use a theme?

Comment: find any other css in the directory.

Comment: @jc david - There aren't any other CSS files in the directory. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you reference style.css that resides in 'themes/default' directory correctly. Otherwise OpenLayers will rely on path to images defined inline, not in CSS classes, which is why your images are loaded from root directory and not 'themes/default/img', I guess.

Comment: Ah. I see. Thanks for your help. How and where do I reference the style.css document correctly?

Comment: Like this: <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme/default/style.css" type="text/css"> Path to css file depends of course on you folder structure. It's importans that 'img' folder is in the same directory as the css file.